# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que estas funciones se ejecuten de manera asíncrona?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando que mi aplicación mida la distancia del usuario hasta un punto en determinado. Para eso, mediante JavaScript asíncrono:

1. Obtengo las coordenadas del usuario
2. Guardo esas coordenadas en el State
3. Mido mediante otra función la distancia entre la ubicación del usuario y la del punto deseado
4. Guardo esa distancia final en el State

El problema es que no se ejecutan en el orden que especifico, y se ejecuta primero la función que mide las distancias **(Punto 3)** antes que el guardado de las coordenadas del usuario en el state **(Punto 1 y 2)**, por lo que la distancia final guardada **(Punto 4)** termina siendo un NaN.

Función que mide la distancia entre dos ubicaciones:

```
getKilometros = (lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) =>{
  let rad = function(x) {return x*Math.PI/180;}
  var R = 6378.137; //Radio de la tierra en km
  var dLat = rad( lat2 - lat1 );
  var dLong = rad( lon2 - lon1 );
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLong/2) * Math.sin(dLong/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;
  return d.toFixed(1); //Retorna un decimal
}
```

Promesa mediante la cual obtengo la ubicación del usuario:

```
getCurrentUbication(){
  return new Promise((res) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res);
  });
}
```

Función que se encarga de los 4 puntos anteriormente mencionados:

```
  setStateUbications(){
      this.getCurrentUbication()  //Ejecución de la promesa de las coordenadas actuales
      .then(res=>this.setState({  //guardado de las coordenadas actuales en el State
          coords:{
            currentUbicationLatitude: res.coords.latitude,
            currentUbicationLongitude: res.coords.longitude,
          }
      }))
      .then(  //Medición de las distancias y guardado en el State
          this.setState({
              kmDistance:  this.getKilometros(this.state.currentUbicationLatitude, this.state.currentUbicationLongitude, 41.38126630740022, 2.122733969315872)
          })
          )
    }
```

Evolución del State:
[image: Console con el State]

La función que engloba estos 4 puntos se llama en el `componentDidMount()`, si la ejecuto en el `render()` sí me da resultados ya que `state.kmDistance` se actualiza constantemente, pero tengo entendido que esto generaría un bucle infinito ya que accede al `setState()`.

Comment: Estas llamando a alguna API-Rest?

Comment: @EnzoPaez sí, JJSONPlaceholder

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu código de las llamadas a las API's? Quizás `async: false` en las configuración de tu llamado te ayude.

Comment: Listo, ya agregue el llamado a la API.

Comment: Funciono bien?..

Comment: No, no funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, pude solucionar el problema cambiando la estructura de manejo de la asincronía. Aún así si alguien sabe cual era el error anterior por favor dígamelo que me interesa, aún no se por que el anterior código no funciona.

Este es el código que funciona:

```
    // Función en caso de éxito de la promesa getCurrentPosition
succes = async(pos) =>{
  // Guardado de las coordenadas en el State 
  await this.setState({
      currentUbicationLatitude: pos.coords.latitude,
      currentUbicationLongitude: pos.coords.longitude,
  })
  // Medición de las distancias y guardado en el State
  this.setState({
    kmDistance:  this.getKilometros(this.state.currentUbicationLatitude, this.state.currentUbicationLongitude, 41.38126630740022, 2.122733969315872)
  })
}

// Promesa que devuelve la ubicación del usuario
getCurrentUbication(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.succes);
}
```